# history.back() showing issues with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using history.back(-1) and also tried history.go(-1) to go to previous URL, it navigates me to previous URL successfully but in Chrome it takes the content from Cache so if I have made any changes through ajax and navigated to other page and want to come back to previous URL it should refresh the page and get the new updated content from DB instead of cache. This problem is with chrome only and might be in Safari 5 as well.

Or is there any way to go to previous URL except by using history object? Well we can do by using **document.referrer** but it not gives me hash(#) values, suppose I have a URL http://www.example.com/home.html#navigate and if I use **document.referrer** it will only give me http://www.example.com/home.html

Please help

Comment: Check "location" object in chrome console and you find how to access different parts of url string.

There's also "location.assign(string url)" which you could use for force refreshing.

Comment: You can use location.hash in javascript to get #navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Disable the file cache, [setting no-cache](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html). (also can be done in backend changing the header from file, but I don't know what backend you are using.)
2. You can use a `setInterval` to validate the `window.location.hash` and put a callback.

   - [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) in the Router may help you.
   - [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) is a very good choice too!
   - You can google for other `pushState` libs.
3. You can save the DOM reference from your page content in a variable to when some content by `xhr` need to apply changes for security, you change it content, so if user use history back, the DOM will be constructed in memory element tree, and the page have been changed at this point. (I haven't tested this, but in theory it could work because you just refer for the instance you browser uses to populate the DOM).

Hope this help you, but with information you gave, I can't go further...